# Visual Studio Code how to launch ASP.Net Core Razor application?

Tags: asp.net-core, browser, visual-studio-code, razor-pages, launching-application

How to launch a simple ASP.Net Core application with Razor pages? I have launch.json but F5 opens up browser which points to non-existing index.html.  I have a simple ASP.Net Core application similar to this: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/signalr/sample

Comment: What is the URL that you enter and how does the "non-existing index.html" look like? I can run the sample without any issue.

Comment: I didn't specify any URL. Just hit F5, browser opens up at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html` and "This 127.0.0.1 page can’t be found"

Comment: I use ConfigureKestrel in order to enable protocol HTTP1.x and HTTP2. However, using IPAddress.Loopback does not work! The browser opens up 127.0.0.1/index.html and show "Page not found"! Modify the URL at the browser address bar to "localhost" works!

Comment: You can try to add the ip address to the ip list by using this command in the terminal: netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1

Comment: netsh: command not found

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes you can change the start page by going to the Properties window for the web project and select the Debug tab. On the 'Launch browser' line enter the starting path

[image]